# Mail Delivery too slow with sendmail

Tags: linux, java, sendmail

We are using javamail to deliver mail for our applications. The mail function runs in a loop to deliver around 100 to 200 mails depending on the range we use.

However, it taking more than an hour to send around 100 mails.

All the mails are send with an attachment (pdf file) of size 14KB.

The mail function is as follows:

```
sendMailWithAttachment("mail@example.in", "password",
                    "192.168.2.160", "25", "false", "false", true, "false",
                    to, subject, body);
```

We are using `sendmail` for mail server and it runs on the same network of the application. So, the latency from application server to mail server is very low.

`sendmail` Version:

```
# sendmail -d0.1
Version 8.13.8
```

If I run `mailq` on the server, it always shows two or three mails pending at a time.

```
# mailq
/var/spool/mqueue (3 requests)
Total requests: 3
```

Load average on the mail server is very low.

```
$w
14:13:45 up 8 days, 59 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.03, 0.03, 0.00
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Does the sendmail deploy any antyspam/antivirus checks?

Comment: Some cause I remember : name resolution is slow; server load average is above the sendmail configured limit ; big files processed by the antivirus are in the queue, other mails are in the queue, network link duplex mismatch (lan connection are slower than routed connection), mail loop.

Comment: No antivirus/antispam checks are deployed